# converting png to ico shrinks the size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, png

I converted a 256px ico file to a 256px png so I could edit it in Photoshop. The problem I'm having is once I'm done in Photoshop, I save the png image, go to IcoFX and convert the 256px png to a ico file, but it shrinks the ico image down to 32px. Why is this?

Comment: In `Icon->Import image` have you specified the correct size?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if/how browsers scale large icons, but The W3C suggests the following<sup>1</sup>:

> The format for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors. The format of the image must be one of PNG (a W3C standard), GIF, or ICO.

---

<sup>1</sup> [w3c.org: How to Add a Favicon to your Site (Draft in development)](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).